# Magento - Add order id to invoice PDF

Tags: invoice, pdf

I need to replace the invoice id to order id on my invoice PDF (see image).
Spent a few hours researching without finding a proper guide on getting started with customising magento's PDF :/ and explored a few extensions but i really don't wanna add an extension for this. So any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way to do this is to overwrite the core PDF model for invoices.

First copy the file

```
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
```

to

```
app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
```

Now open the new file and replace the following line

```
Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $invoice->getIncrementId()
```

with

```
Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order # ') . $order->getId()
```

Comment: that worked ! now just a small problem, i get the order nr but only the last digits, so the order nr is 100002612 and in the pdf it only shows 2612, its not a huge problem but it would help to get the full number any ide how to fix that ?

Comment: Never mind i figured it out i just replaced `getId()` with `getIncrementId()`